# Calling simple AJAX WebMethod always results in "fail" callback

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json, webmethod

Below code is my server side code. (C#)

```
            [WebMethod]
            public static string InsertCV(string edu)
            {             
                return "";
            }
```

And Below code is my client side code. (ASP.NET)

```
           var edu = {"education":[{"university":"111","speciality":"222","faculty":"333","degree":"444","start":"555","end":"666"}]}

            var post = $.ajax(
             {
                 type: "POST",
                 data: edu,
                 url: "Add_CV.aspx/InsertCV",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 async: true,
                 cache: false
             })
            post.done(function (data, teStatus, jqXHR) {
                if (data.d == "")
                { alert("ok"); }
            });
            post.fail(function (jqXHR, e) {
                alert("error");
            });
```

I would like to send user's data to server with ajax post method. But everytime  `post.fail()` function executes.
Please help me that where is my mistake.
May be in server side `InsertCV(string edu)` , `string` is not appropriate for this situtate. I don't know.

Comment: I am sorry , it was my mistake

Comment: may be you are passing data in wrong way. Just try JSON.stringify(edu) in data object of AJAX Call.
Thanks

Comment: @user3624946 Use the browser developer tools to inspect the request and server response - i.e. was it a 403? 404? 5xx? Also, try attaching a debugger to the ASP.NET code and see if there are any exceptions of note.

Comment: @Arpit Jain, I have tried it, but result is the same.

Comment: @user2864740 , I tried and got error 500.

Comment: @user3624946 Then definitely attach a debugger - you may have to *disable* "Just My Code", but there should be an exception thrown :)

Comment: could uyyou remove square bracets,

Comment: @sakir ,  why should I do this ?

Comment: Please use the code i posted below and try out once.
thanks

Comment: as it contains json array as well,

Comment: u can try first stringify json array later stringify all edu ,may be it work

Comment: in that way u can send string insteaf of object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
public static string InsertCV(string edu)
```

is expecting a single parameter called `edu` that is of type `string`.  Your AJAX call is instead passing in an un-named JavaScript object, which is *not* a string.  The framework code that is trying to parse the request is never matching your `InsertCV` method at all, and eventually gives up with a `500 - Internal Server Error` result.

To pass a complex structure like this into a `WebMethod` you need to define a compatible .NET class to deserialize into.  For instance:

```
// outer type for the parameter
public class EduType
{
    public Education[] education;

    // inner type for the 'education' array
    public class Education
    {
        public string university;
        public string speciality;
        public string faculty;
        public string degree;
        public string start;
        public string end;
    }
}

[WebMethod]
public static string InsertCV(EduType edu)
{
    return edu == null ? "null" : string.Format("{0} Items", edu.education.Length);
}
```

If the JSON string will deserialize into this format then this method is the one that should get called.

Comment: I'll try your answer and will write result.

Comment: It was very helpfull for me. Thanks. I need 10 reputation to share my answer to my own question. I only used `Education class` and `InsertCV(Education[]  education)`. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for your problem.

Here is the code :

as cs page :

```
[WebMethod]
public static string InsertCV(object education)
{
   return "";
}
```

and for calling this method :

```
var edu = { "education": [{ "university": "111", "speciality": "222", "faculty": "333", "degree": "444", "start": "555", "end": "666"}] }

   var post = $.ajax(
   {
      type: "POST",
      data:  JSON.stringify(edu),
      url: "ServiceTest.aspx/InsertCV",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      async: true,
      cache: false
    })
    post.done(function (data, teStatus, jqXHR) {
        if (data.d == "")
        { 
          alert("ok"); 
        }
   });
   post.fail(function (jqXHR, e) {
        alert("error");
   });
```

if this is helpful to you, Please mark as correct.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @OlafDietsche ,
There are mainly two changes..
1. Took "object" instead of "string" into WebHTTP Method and 
2. Pass data from AJAX inside the JSON.Stringify Method.
Might be this will helpful to you... 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As asked by @user2864740, your method InsertCV does not do anything. I suggest starting by testing your webmethod by setting a breakpoint in the InsertCV method, to see if this get hit when browsed to. Secondly from your AJAX post method you send a JSON array, but in the InsertCV method, you only expect a single string. This have to match. When you can trigger the WebMethod from your AJAX call, then go on and add handling for writing to a backend database

Comment: I tried to check with breakpoint , but  as if program don't see breakpoint. In my mind data don't come to server side. may be json type is not correct.